# i want to parse my script file by regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i have a script file like below

```
[grade]
`[achievement]`

[gold multiple]
250

[level]
34
99

[pre required quest]
38
[/pre required quest]
```

for example:

```
lex("grade") return "`[achievement]`"

lex("level") return "34,99"
```

may be i can do it by linq, but i don't find a way

i tried

```
scripts = File.ReadAllText(scriptFilePath);
string gradeKeyword = @"(?<=\[grade\]\r\n).*?\r\n*(?=\[.*\]\r\n)"
Regex reg = new Regex(gradeKeyword);
Match mat = reg.Match(scripts);
```

it didn't work(which i want to get `[achievement]`)

BTW, can i do that by linq?

Comment: Can you define your input format better. It's not entirely free from ambiguity. It seems that some "tags" only need opening but some (e.g. "*pre required quest*") also require closing.

Comment: I agree with @spender - can you change the input file format? XML or similar would be better suited to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try not using a regex.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetScriptSection(string file, string section)
{
    var startMatch = string.Format("[{0}]", section);
    var endMatch = string.Format("[/{0}]", section);
    var lines = file.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();

    int startIndex = lines.FindIndex(f => f == startMatch) + 1;
    int endIndex = lines.FindLastIndex(f => f == endMatch);

    if(endIndex == -1)
    {
        endIndex = lines.FindIndex(startIndex,  f => f.StartsWith("[") && lines.IndexOf(f) > startIndex);
        endIndex = endIndex == -1 ? lines.Count : endIndex;
    }

    return lines.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).ToList();
}
```

But I would just use YAML, XML, or some other well used format instead of rolling my own.

Comment: +1 for YAML instead of rolling your own scripting system. Something someone else invented is almost always easier and probably better too.

Comment: +1 for not using Regexes when the problem [does not need them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Least_Power).

Answer (score 0):

.NET regular expressions default to not matching across line breaks. You have to specify the [RegexOptions.SingleLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option.

Answer (score 0):

Try following expresion:

```
string gradeKeyword = "\\[level\\]\\r\\n([^\\[].+\\r\\n)+";
```